# Which quantity could hold its convergence under Gromov-Hausdorff convergence?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, manifolds

Recently I've been reading T.H.Colding's paper of Ricci curvature and volume convergence. A proof of the continuity of volume functions was given under the lower Ric bounded condition.
Having searched online with failure, I wonder if there were some results of other quantity's regularity under the Gromov-Hausdorff topology.

P.S.
I want to find some other properties that could change like the volume of manifolds with a lower Ric bound under the GH-topology.

Thanks